# Where is the PatchMatch feature in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

Where is the Patch Match feature of Photoshop CS5 shown in [this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgKjs8ZjQNg)  I searched in all photoshop but only thing their is Content Aware Fill, no interactively patch and move objects like the video. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgKjs8ZjQNg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PatchMatch is an experimental algorithm/feature that was used in Content Aware Fill. I assume that's all they could debug in a year and couldn't fit the other pieces in before deadline.

Unless you want to [configure, debug, and compile yourself](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/), that is.